# html How to relative path

Tags: html, css

How to get from thispage.html to thatpage.css using relative link

```
public_html
  ├── folder1
  |    |__subfolder
  |          |__thatpage.css
  ├── folder2
  │   |__subfolder
  |          |__thispage.html
```

I tried this

```
<link href="../../folder1/subfolder/thatpage.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: That should work. What are you seeing that makes you think it's not?

Comment: should be `folder2`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a (document relative path), which only works when the website is on a server or local server environment like MAMP. You can however use a (root relative path) like this /folder1/subfolder/thatpage.css.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the folder structure given, what you tried should have worked.

Alternately you could use an absolute path by starting with a `/`. This will start from the root of the domain, eg.

```
/folder1/subfolder/thatpage.css
```

is equivalent to

```
http://example.com/folder1/subfolder/thatpage.css
```